# Fetching next row of mysql result to compare an index with present row which if being same -> loop output

Tags: php, html, mysql, web-applications, phpmyadmin

So I am generating a report dynamically by fetching values by mysqli_query. This is the current output - > https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD3mm.png What I want is that while we are echoing the tasks for the same project the project column display the project title just once and spans through number of tasks under that project, that is TIME MS should appear just once

edit - Table Structure -

log(**log_id**,proj_id,task_id,user_id,hours,date)

projects(**proj_id**,title,desc)

tasks(**task_id**,title,desc,user_id,proj_id)

```
$q="SELECT proj_id, task_id,SUM(hours),date    
 FROM log
WHERE user_id =$row[0] AND date >= '$s' AND date<= '$e'  
GROUP BY proj_id, task_id";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$q) or die(mysqli_error($con));
while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($res)) /*while rows exist select each row to 
                                     extract and display project name task                                   
                                     name and sometime calc. 

                                    Problem - I wanna display just one cell  
                                     of project name till the tasks under that 
                                     project are displayed. I know this is 
                                     achieved by rowspan but using that here                                       
                                     is skewing up my table */


      {       
         $q="SELECT `title` FROM `projects` WHERE proj_id=$row[0]";
         $res=mysqli_query($con,$q) or die(mysqli_error($con));
         $ptitle=mysqli_fetch_row($res);
         $q= "SELECT title FROM tasks WHERE task_id =$row[1]";
         $res=mysqli_query($con,$q) or die(mysqli_error($con));
         $row=mysqli_fetch_row($res);
         $time=round(($row[2]/$total[0])*100);

         echo '
         <td>'
          .$ptitle[0].    //using rowspan here is skewing up the  table as                                             
                          //  the loop executes seperately for each task    
        '</td>         
          <td>'
          .$row2[0].
        '</td>  
          <td>'
          .$time.
         '</td>
         </tr>';
      }
```

I know there is faulty logic somewhere, but im just not able to figure it out. I need to somehow check if we are still displaying tasks for the same project and count the no. of tasks and set
                       `<td rowspan='.$count.'>Project Title</td>`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add the script but i can tell you the algorithm

1.First Fetch rows/array

2.Save the project title in a PHP global variable

3.Compare the next result(title) with the previous title.

if(same)
   {
   use javascript to increase the rowspan
   }
   else
   {
   Store new title inside the variable
   }

Note :- For doing this you will have to set dynamic id's for table row.
Example

```
<?PHP
while(true)
{
$i++;
<tr id="$i"></tr>
}
?>
```